# Ruby on Rails Date using "/" or "-"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I feel like this shouldn't be a problem, but can't seem to find any solutions online with dates in Ruby.  I am receiving a date from a form, and re-formatting it so it is in the correct format for the database.  As I have it currently the strptime date format is using "-".  If the user decides to use "/" instead, it breaks the code.  Is there a "wildcard" that can be used so it doesn't matter how the user separates the dates?

```
DateTime.strptime( params[:course][:start_date], "%m-%d-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.parse "2001-01-01" # => #<DateTime: 2001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2451911j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
DateTime.parse "2001/01/01" # => #<DateTime: 2001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2451911j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse

Comment: Thanks Kyle.  That seems to accept both the "/" and "-" but oddly, it parses it as year/day/month.  When I use the date 06/12/2015, it parses it as 2015/12/06, and when I use a date such as 06/15/2015, it gives an invalid date error.  However, the date is being sent to the controller correctly as "06/12/2015"

Comment: The only other suggest I'd have is to look into the chronic gem - https://github.com/mojombo/chronic